# Creating netbeans platform application bundles

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-platform

I am developing a [Netbeans Platform](http://platform.netbeans.org) app. I assume there will be three types of typical users and each of these groups will use a slightly different set of modules. So I would like to create 4 different bundles (for the three user types + everything). This is similar to what Netbeans itself offers: there are [5 different downloads](https://netbeans.org/downloads/index.html) (Java SE, Java EE, C/C++, HTML5 & PHP and All). Note that this is just the default, the user can still download the Java SE bundle and then go to the Update Center and manually install all the plugins from the Java EE bundle.

How is this achieved? Do I have to manually create several different nbproject/project.properties and nbproject/platform.properties files (and then manually keep them up-to-date) and use external scripts to build the suite with each of them ? Or is there some less hacky way?

Answer (score 1):

Create three module suites. Each of them will target one user type and can have 1 or more modules. Configure them to use their own cluster (you need to look it up in docs, README in NETBEANS_HOME/harness can be useful). Then it should be possible to customize NetBeans installer to build what you need.

NetBeans distros are same thing: set of clusters built together and wrapper with installer.

Comment: Thanks. What if distro A and distro B share some modules? Then I have to create an extra cluster for those?

BTW Here is the doc about clusters: http://wiki.netbeans.org/DevFaqWhatIsACluster.

Comment: Possibly. One cluster can depend on another but try to avoid circular dependencies.